# unable to load 3rd party library to aurelia cli

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to install `jwt-decode` to my aurelia cli application. I've `npm` installed the library and added it to my `aurelia.json` file:

```
"dependencies": [
    ... other deps
    {
        "name": "jwt-decode",
        "path": "../node_modules/jwt-decode/lib",
        "main": "index"
    }
    ... other deps
]
```

When I run `au build` or `au run` everything compiles and I can see the the cli is tracing the `jwt-decode` package; however, when I try to include it in a file I get an error:

```
src/stores/auth/service.ts(4,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jwt-decode'.
[22:13:04] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Error: src/stores/auth/service.ts(4,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jwt-decode'.
[22:13:04] TypeScript: 1 semantic error
[22:13:04] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
```

I've even tried adding it to the prepend property but it did not work. I'm also using typescript so I don't know if that could be causing an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dependencies` section in `aurelia.json` is correct.

This error is related to TypeScript: typing definition (.d.ts file) is missing for 'jwt-decode' package.

You can install it by `typings install dt~jwt-decode --global --save`

After that, import it as a global module: `import * as jwt from 'jwt-decode';`